# Show decimals with jquery but not if decimals are zero

Tags: jquery

Ihave this code,, and is working as intended, but I need to hide the decimals if the are something like .0000, for now I'm ussing .toFixed, but it renders the zeroes no mather what

```
$('#peso_combinado').keyup(function() {
    var peso_combinado = $('#peso_combinado').val();
    var cantidad = Number($('#sacos').val());
    var peso_tara = Number($('#peso_tara').val());


    var medividen = 0;
    var total_tara = 0;
    var neto_total = 0;

    total_tara = peso_tara * cantidad;
    medividen = peso_combinado / cantidad;



    neto_total = (peso_combinado - total_tara) / 100;

    $('#peso_total').val(peso_combinado.toFixed(4));
    $('#total_tara').val(total_tara.toFixed(4));
    $('#peso_neto').val(neto_total.toFixed(4));
    $('.total_combinado').val(medividen.toFixed(4));
    $('#total_por_saco').attr('name', '');
    $('.total_combinado').attr('name', 'peso_proporcional');
    $('#total_por_saco').attr('id', '');
    $('.total_combinado').attr('id', 'peso_proporcional');
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you are wanting to remove them **only** in instances where **all** of the trailing digits were 0s the easiest way might be to use `.replace(/\.0+$/,'')`

The regex used here `/\.0+$/` basically says to match any group of characters that starts with a `.` followed by at least one but up to any number of `0`s that terminates at the end of the string.

#### As an example:

```js
//when float has only 0s after the decimal place, replace them
var medividen = 46.0000
$('.total_combinado').append(medividen.toFixed(4).replace(/\.0+$/,'') +'<br>');


//wont affect floats that do have digits other than 0 after the decimal
medividen = 46.3400
$('.total_combinado').append(medividen.toFixed(4).replace(/\.0+$/,'')+'<br>');


//also wont hurt floats that start with 00 but then have other numbers
medividen = 46.0034
$('.total_combinado').append(medividen.toFixed(4).replace(/\.0+$/,'')+'<br>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total_combinado"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add plus (+) in front of variable like this:

```
var number = 1.3000001;
var total = +number.toFixed(2);
```

In your example:

```
$('#peso_total').val(+peso_combinado.toFixed(4));
```

Source:
https://javascript.info/number

Answer (score 0):

`.toFixed(x)` returns a string. Just parse it as a float again:

```
function tofixed(val) {
    return parseFloat(val.toFixed(4));
}

$('#peso_combinado').keyup(function () {
    var peso_combinado = $('#peso_combinado').val();
    var cantidad = Number($('#sacos').val());
    var peso_tara = Number($('#peso_tara').val());


    var medividen = 0;
    var total_tara = 0;
    var neto_total = 0;


    total_tara = peso_tara * cantidad;
    medividen = peso_combinado / cantidad;



    neto_total = (peso_combinado - total_tara) / 100;

    $('#peso_total').val(tofixed(peso_combinado));
    $('#total_tara').val(tofixed(total_tara));
    $('#peso_neto').val(tofixed(neto_total));
    $('.total_combinado').val(tofixed(medividen));
    $('#total_por_saco').attr('name', '');
    $('.total_combinado').attr('name', 'peso_proporcional');
    $('#total_por_saco').attr('id', '');
    $('.total_combinado').attr('id', 'peso_proporcional');
});
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need to define a new function for this.  Just call it directly like `parseFloat($('#peso_combinado').val().toFixed(4));` since defining a new function adds no benefit here.  Otherwise, a good solution

Comment: @DelightedD0D just added the function to make it slightly neater. Also if the OP needs it to be used more than showed above it would make it easier for them :)

Comment: I get the idea in theory,  but you're really just creating a new function that directly calls an existing function. It doesnt matter how many times you need to perform the function call you're still doubling the number of functions that have to be called. The only way adding a new function would add any performance or readability benefit would be if the new `tofixed(val)` function contained several lines of code. There's just no reason to absract this.